# Perl Regex - Getting Text Before and After Match

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am parsing a tab delimited file line by line:

```
Root rootrank 1 Bacteria domain .72 Firmicutes phylum 1 Clostridia class 1 etc.
```

=

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp($line);
}
```

On every line, I want to capture the 1st entry before and after a particular match. For example, for the match `phylum`, I want to capture the entries `Firmicutes` and `1`. For the match `domain`, I want to capture the entries `Bacteria` and `.72`. How would I write the regex to do this?

Sidenote: I can't simply split the line by tab into an array and use the index because sometimes a category is missing or there are extra categories, and that causes the entries to be shifted by one or two indices. And I want to avoid writing blocks of if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @words = qw(phylum domain);
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    for my $word (@words) {
        my ($before, $after) = $_ =~ /(\S+)(?:\t\Q$word\E\t)(\S+)/i;
        say "word: $word\tbefore: $before\tafter: $after";
    }
}

__DATA__
Root rootrank 1 Bacteria domain .72 Firmicutes phylum 1 Clostridia class 1 etc.
```

**Output:**

```
word: phylum    before: Firmicutes  after: 1
word: domain    before: Bacteria    after: .72
```

Comment: how do I modify the regex you wrote above to match words on a tab delimited line? In the example I wrote, the words are separated only by 1 space

Answer (score 3):

You can still split the input, then map the words to indices, and use than use the indices corresponding to the matches to extract the neighbouring cells:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @matches = qw( phylum domain );

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @cells = split /\t/;
    my %indices;
    @indices{ @cells } = 0 .. $#cells;
    for my $match (@matches) {
        if (defined( my $index = $indices{$match} )) {
            say join "\t", @cells[ $index - 1 .. $index + 1 ];
        }
    }
}
```

What's missing:

1. You should handle the case when $index == 0 or $index == $#cells.
2. You should handle the case where some words are repeated in one line.

Answer (score 3):

```
 my $file = "file2.txt";
 open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to Open the file $file for reading: $!\n";
 while (my $line = <$fh>) {
     chomp $line;
     while ($line =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\.?\d+)/g) {
     my ($before, $match, $after) = ($1, $2, $3);
     print "Before: $before  Match: $match  After: $after\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply use the following *regex* to capture the words `before` and `after` of a matched word:

```
(?<LSH>[\w.]+)[\s\t](?<MATCH>.*?)[\s\t](?<RHS>[\w.]+)
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4K4d6Y/2)

Comment: @cooldood3490 check updated answer. now you can match space and tab at the same time

Comment: tabs are matched by `\s`, and you don't need a char class if just matching `\s`, so both `[\s\t]` can be replaced by `\s`.